# How to display notification if request takes a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is what i've done:

```
response.config.responseTiming = performance.now();
var timing = response.config.responseTiming - response.config.requestTiming;

if (timing > 15000) {
    var toastr = $injector.get('toastr');
    toastr.info($filter('i18n')('_request_info_'));
    angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
        preventOpenDuplicates: true
    });
}
```

But the problem is, the notification will appear when the request is completed, not when 15-sec pass(example: if it goes over 30sec, it will display notification after 30 sec not on 15 sec). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Because 30 000 is bigger than 15 000. Why do you need to accomplish this? Maybe you need another approach.

Comment: Do you do that in the response handler? We need more context

Comment: Well, sometimes it happens that request takes longer than usuall, i thought that after sometime for example after 15 sec user gets some notification on screen. This works only when i get final response